# JavaScript anonymous functions - how to determine available parameters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, anonymous-function

I am using the following code snippet from the documentation of a tool (FullScale Dangle):

```
$scope.displayCoord = function(type, term) {
    console.log(term);
    console.log(type);
};
```

This function is called on-click after being routed through the tool's own library. According to the documentation, I have the parameters `type`, and `term` available to the function after the onclick.

How can I determine what additional parameters are available?

Comment: By far the easiest way to know what they are and how to use them would be to look them up in the documentation.

Comment: The documentation for this was woefully incomplete. I ended up sorting through the mini-fied code and learning where the developer calls the callback function.

Comment: Yeah, that kind of sucks. Sometimes it's necessary though. You _can_ do as Niet suggests below, but figuring why that argument is there and how you use it still won't be obvious. You may still have to trace through the code of a poorly documented library to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `arguments` array-like object. This means you can do `arguments.length` to see how many there are, and access them as `arguments[0]` (`type`), `arguments[1]` (`term`), and any others that may be there.

Answer (score 1):

Using the arguments object, something like this should do it:

```
var f = function (args1, args2) {console.log(arguments);}("foo", "bar", "bing");
```

["foo", "bar", "bing"]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answers, you can use the **arguments** object. Here's more information available on it's use. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments